# C++/ arguments in h. file

Tags: c++

I read a book, which gives example of .h file, that equal to interface of queue in java:

```
void InitQueue(Queue* pQueue, int iSize);
bool Insert(Queue* pQueue, const Item* pItem);
bool Extract(Queue* pQueue, Item** pItem);
bool GetFirst(const Queue* pQueue, Item** pItem);
bool IsFull(const Queue* pQueue);
bool IsEmpty(const Queue* pQueue);
```

I didn't understand two things:

1. Why in `Extract, GetFirst` The second argument is of type `Item**` and not `Item*`? What is mean when we wrtoe such a thing?
2. Why in some functions (`IsFull, IsEmpty`, ..) we get as argument `const Queue*` and not simply `Queue*`?

Comment: Was the book written by a [2-star programmer](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer)?

Comment: Is this really C++? It looks like the kind of thing done in C. (Then again, perhaps this is some technique I don't know of)

Comment: Because they want to be able to change the pointer you pass in to the function. If it were just `Item * pItem`, you would be passing a copy of your pointer, which if they change it inside the function, would not be visible outside of the function

Comment: Also, what book is this?

Comment: @Pubby You don't find bool or const in C (ok, you do get stdbool in C99) it's just old C++ :-)

Comment: @Benj `const` is in C, and `bool` could be a typedef.

Comment: @Pubby Yeh, I just realised that, it didn't used to be, it's a recent addition.

Comment: (And by recent I mean C89 ;-)

Comment: @Benj: C has had `const` arguments for a long time. The only difference between this code and C is the use of `bool`. That one keyword does not qualify the code as C++. It's C± code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IsFull() and IsEmpty() take const arguments because it implies that they will not change the Queue object; it is constant, and will not be modified.

Extract and GetFirst use ** because of this:

```
int a;           // Declares an int
a = 2;           // Sets a to 2
int *b = &a;     // Declares a pointer pointing to that int
*b = 4;          // Sets a to 4
int **c = &b;    // Declares a pointer pointing to that pointer to that int
**c = 6;         // Sets a to 6
```

If I were to pass c into a function:

```
int global_var;

int main() {
  modify_ptr(c);
}

void modify_ptr(int **ptr)
{
  *ptr = &global_var;
}
```

The pointer I just passed in was itself modified; **c is now pointing to global_var instead of a.

The reason you pass these pointers into getfirst and extract is because those are "getter" functions - you want them to return a pointer to the data. So they need to be able to return a pointer, and the method these employ is to pass a pointer to a pointer, like in the above example, so they can modify what you pass them to point to the correct element.

Answer (score 2):

**Why in `Extract`, `GetFirst` The second argument is of type `Item**` and not `Item*`? What is mean when we wrote such a thing?**

So that the pointer can be changed inside the function.
Most likely, It means that the `Item` pointer will be passed by the caller but will be allocated inside the function. You cannot do so by just passing a pointer by value because that would allocate memory to a copy of the pointer and not the original pointer being passed.

It is difficult to say why the programmer uses this semantics of caller passing the pointer and function allocating it.Ideally, One would expect a source-sink mechanism.

**Why in some functions (`IsFull`, `IsEmpty`, ..) we get as argument `const Queue*` and not simply `Queue*`?**

For **[const correctness](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html)**!
It indicates to the user of the function that the pointed to data will not be changed inside the function.

Answer (score 1):

> Why in Extract, GetFirst The second argument is of type Item** and not Item*? What is mean when we wrtoe such a thing?

Those are outputs. The queue apparently comprises a bunch of pointers to items. Since it's a pointer, I would have made `Extract` and `GetFirst` take just one argument and return a pointer. A null pointer would indicate failure. The developers didn't do it this way. Instead they used an old, C-style paradigm. Why? Who knows. This is not the best way to write these.

> Why in some functions (IsFull, IsEmpty, ..) we get as argument const Queue* and not simply Queue*?

Marking the argument as `const` tells the user of the code that the function will not do anything to the contents of the argument. Marking such undisturbed reference and pointer arguments as `const` is a good programming practice.